# How to animate dynamically created collapsible sets in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm currently creating an application that receives data from a server and then dynamically creates collapsible elements. Now I have code that allows for the animation of the opening and closing of the collapsible elements across the whole application:

```
$('[data-role="collapsible"]').bind('expand', function () {
            $(this).children().slideDown(500);
        }).bind('collapse', function () {
            $(this).children().next().slideUp(500);
        });
```

Now this code doesn't work on the dynamically created collapsible elements. Thus what I have tried to do is the following:

```
$(document).on('pagechange','#resultssearch',
    function()
    {
        $('[data-role="collapsible"]').bind('expand', function () {
            $(this).children().slideDown(500);
        }).bind('collapse', function () {
            $(this).children().next().slideUp(500);
        });

    });
```

So on the page where the dynamic collapsible elements are added to I tried to add the above page event. But some how this also doesn't seem to work. How would I get dynamically generated to animate?

As shown in the suggested answers the code that works is given as:

```
$(document).on('expand', '[data-role="collapsible"]', function () {
     $(this).children().slideDown(500);
 }).on('collapse', '[data-role="collapsible"]', function () {
     $(this).children().next().slideUp(500);
 });
```

How ever this doesn't work 100%. The events of children collapsibles end up affecting the parent collapsibles, this can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CphEb/). Is there any way of stopping the children collapsibles from doing this?

Answer (score 3):

Event delegation, my friend. You'll have to bind that element either to a static parent or to the `document` object. If you're dynamically adding the collapsible, adding an event to an element which doesn't exist at that particular point of time is pointless. The approach here is that you add the `expand` and `collapse` event to the immediate parent (which already exists on `pagechange` ( or rather use `pageshow` ) or add it to the `document` which exists all the time, like this :

```
 $(document).on('expand', '[data-role="collapsible"]', function () {
     $(this).children().slideDown(500);
 }).on('collapse', '[data-role="collapsible"]', function () {
     $(this).children().next().slideUp(500);
 });
```

Or, simply, join them up like this :

```
$(document).on({
    "expand": function () {
        $(this).children().slideDown(500);
    },
    "collapse": function () {
        $(this).children().next().slideUp(500);
    }
}, '[data-role="collapsible"]');
```

[More info in docs.](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Thank you for such a good answer! I just want to ask if I have multiple collapsible sets with in each other how would I get the events to correspond to each collapsible set? Eg if I have a collapsible with in another should I close I close the collapsible set it also ends up closing the parent collapsible

Comment: The events work for parent and child collapsibles just the child events affect the parent. Eg if I close a child collapsible it ends up closing the parent. Anyway of fixing this?

Comment: can u make a fiddle for this at jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just add delegation?

```
$('body').on('expand','[data-role="collapsible"]', function () {
        $(this).children().slideDown(500);
    }).bind('collapse', function () {
        $(this).children().next().slideUp(500);
    });
```

This just means every matching of [data-role..... will get fired on because the body actually has the event on it, it just basically sends it down to the child.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is simply change "children" to "child" so that it only deals with one "generation"

```
$(document).on('expand', '[data-role="collapsible"]', function () {
     $(this).child().slideDown(500);
 }).on('collapse', '[data-role="collapsible"]', function () {
     $(this).child().next().slideUp(500);
 });
```